Auth0 Credentials Manager in Android app
I am building an Android app that communicates with a REST API using Retrofit2 and uses Auth0 for authentication. The Android app needs to store access token from Auth0 and use it to authorize its requests. For storing, refreshing and retrieving credentials, I am using Secure Credentials Manager from Auth0. Everything works, but I am curious if I can improve the method for retrieving only the access token from Secure Credentials Manager or improve the whole concept of adding access token to each Retrofit request.
Currently I have one class that takes SecureCredentialsManager as parameter. It has a method getAccessToken() that returns only access token. Then I consume that method from MyCredentialsManager class (code below) using dependency injection in class that implements Interceptor from OkHttp3.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
My class for managing credentials:
public class MyCredentialsManager {  
    private final SecureCredentialsManager secureCredentialsManager;  
      
    public MyCredentialsManager(SecureCredentialsManager secureCredentialsManager) {  
        this.secureCredentialsManager = secureCredentialsManager;  
    }  
      
    public void saveCredentials(Credentials credentials) {  
        secureCredentialsManager.saveCredentials(credentials);  
    }  

    public String getAccessToken() {  
        Credentials credentials = getSyncCredentials();
        return credentials.getAccessToken();  
    }  
     
    private Credentials getSyncCredentials() {
        final Object lock = new Object();  
        final Credentials[] credentialsHolder = new Credentials[1];  
        final Exception[] exceptionHolder = new Exception[1];  
          
        secureCredentialsManager.getCredentials(new Callback<Credentials, CredentialsManagerException>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onSuccess(Credentials credentials) {  
                synchronized (lock) {  
                credentialsHolder[0] = credentials;  
                    lock.notifyAll();  
                }  
            }  
              
            @Override  
            public void onFailure(@NonNull CredentialsManagerException e) {  
                synchronized (lock) {  
                    exceptionHolder[0] = new UserNotAuthenticatedException(); 
                    lock.notifyAll();  
                }  
            }  
        });  
              
        synchronized (lock) {  
            try {  
                lock.wait();  
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  
            }  
        }  
          
        if (exceptionHolder[0] != null) {  
            if (exceptionHolder[0] instanceof UserNotAuthenticatedException) {  
                try {  
                    throw (UserNotAuthenticatedException) exceptionHolder[0];  
                } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {  
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);  
                }  
            } else {  
                throw new RuntimeException(exceptionHolder[0]);  
            }  
        }  
        return credentialsHolder[0];  
    }
}

That is how I use getAccessToken() in the Interceptor class:
.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + myCredentialsManager.getAccessToken())


Update
This is how I call Repository from Model class which I use in MainActivityViewModel. To inject Model to ViewModel I am using ViewModelProvider in MainActivity class and ViewModelProvider.Factory with a custom initializer.
public class MainActivityModel {  
  
private final UserRepositoryImpl userRepository;  
  
    public MainActivityModel(UserRepositoryImpl userRepository) {  
        this.userRepository = userRepository;  
    }  
    
    public LiveData<ArrayList<String>> getUserData() {  
        final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> userData = new MutableLiveData<>();  
        userRepository.fetchUserData(new RetrofitApiResponse<List<UserDataResponse>>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onSuccess(List<UserDataResponse> data) {  
                // Handle response
            }  
            
            @Override  
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {  
                // Handle error
            }  
        });  
    
        return userData;  
    }
}

User repository communicates with Restful API using Retrofit2.
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
      
    private final RetrofitApi retrofitApi;  
      
    public UserRepositoryImpl(RetrofitApi retrofitApi) {  
        this.retrofitApi = retrofitApi;
    }  
      
    @Override  
    public void fetchUserData(final RetrofitApiResponse<List<UserDataResponse>> retrofitApiResponse) {  
        retrofitApi.getUserData().enqueue(new Callback<List<UserDataResponse>>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserDataResponse>> call, Response<List<UserDataResponse>> response) {  
                retrofitApiResponse.onSuccess(response.body());  
            }  
              
            @Override  
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserDataResponse>> call, Throwable throwable) {  
                retrofitApiResponse.onError(throwable);  
            }  
        });  
    }
}

Retrofit uses Interceptor to add access token to each request. The token is provided from TokenManagement class.
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {  
  
    private final TokenManagement tokenManagement;  
      
    public AuthInterceptor(TokenManagement tokenManagement) {  
        this.tokenManagement = tokenManagement;  
    }  
      
    @NonNull  
    @Override  
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {  
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()  
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenManagement.getAccessToken())   
        .build();  
        return chain.proceed(request);  
    }  
}

public class TokenManagement {  
    private final SecureCredentialsManager secureCredentialsManager;  
      
    public MyCredentialsManager(SecureCredentialsManager secureCredentialsManager) {  
        this.secureCredentialsManager = secureCredentialsManager;  
    }  
    
    public String getAccessToken() {  
        Credentials credentials = getSyncCredentials();
        return credentials.getAccessToken();  
    }  
     
    private Credentials getSyncCredentials() {
        final Object lock = new Object();  
        AtomicReference<Credentials> credentialsHolder = new AtomicReference<>();  
        AtomicReference<CredentialsManagerException> exceptionHolder = new AtomicReference<>();  
          
        secureCredentialsManager.getCredentials(new Callback<Credentials, CredentialsManagerException>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onSuccess(Credentials credentials) {  
                credentialsHolder.set(credentials); 
                synchronized (lock) {   
                    lock.notifyAll();  
                }  
            }  
              
            @Override  
            public void onFailure(@NonNull CredentialsManagerException e) {  
                exceptionHolder.set(e); 
                synchronized (lock) {   
                    lock.notifyAll();  
                }  
            }  
        });  
          
        synchronized (lock) {  
            try {  
                lock.wait();  
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  
            }  
        }  
          
        if (exceptionHolder.get() != null) {
            try {
                throw exceptionHolder.get();
            } catch (CredentialsManagerException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
          
        return credentialsHolder.get();
    }
}


Never ever use the "My" prefix. Teachers like it when they want a quick and dirty way to resolve a naming conflict between an interface and their example implementation. Everywhere else it is redundant, uninformative and only gives you an excuse to skip the thought process required for making up a meaningful and descriptive name, making your code less readable and maintainable. Teachers teach because they can't code. You shouldn't listen to their advice. :)
Instead of single element arrays I would use AtomicReference objects instead. Their name and purpose implies that they will contain a reference to an object that will be provided later. With a single element array you have to read the surrounding code to figure that out.
The code snippet lacks context on how you are calling it. But if you're calling it from the main thread, then you would be violating the principle of not doing blocking operations in the main thread. Instead you should offload the loading of credentials to a background task.

Thank you verry much for your answer and suggestions. I tried to follow your advice about AtomicReference and I hope I implemented it correctly in the updated question where I provided more context. As for blocking the main thread you are right, I am calling the function from the main thread. I am trying to offload the task using ExecutorService but I am not sure if I should separate the program to a new thread already in the UserRepositoryImpl as it is also a long-running operation or should I do it differently.
